# class inheritance in objective-c falls short in this case. is there any alternatives?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

class AGImageVC

class AGVideoVC inherits from AGImageVC

class AGAdvancedImageVC inherits from AGImageVC

class AGAdvancedVideoVC inherits from ????

AGAdvancedVideoVC should have implementation from both AGAdvancedImageVC and AGVideoVC. But that's not possible...

I've also been thinking about category, but same problems would definitely be more obvious.

Comment: My goal is to not duplicate code.

Comment: but Categories are the right answer, i think...

Comment: what makes categories to be the right answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to think of class inheritance as a tree in Obj-C. Each class can have multiple sub-classes, but sub-classes can only have one parent. Objective-C lacks the concept of multiple inheritance as we traditionally understand it. People have found various ways to 'fake' multiple inheritance, which are discussed in the links below (personally, I wouldn't recommend them).

There is a fairly detailed explanation of your options regarding multiple inheritance on this Cocoa mailing list post from a few years back: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/131033-multiple-inheritance-and-objective.html

Another discussion on the subject here:
http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MultipleInheritance

Comment: tight answer! thanks, but don't you think multiple inheritance is missing in objective-c, or how do you come around this problem of mine?

Comment: The decision to omit multiple inheritance from Objective-C is by design (the language is fairly heavily influenced by SmallTalk). There's an argument to be made that multiple inheritance is less than ideal, although you may not buy that. As mentioned in other answers, if you really need it you should use protocols, but if you take the language as it was intended to be used you should try to avoid multiple inheritance.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems almost possible to not do one of following in my case: a) write meta-code or b) write duplicate code

Answer (score 2):

That's as close as you can get (using message forwarding) to behavior similar to multiple inheritance. This is not nice design in Objective-C, however. Flat inheritance hierarchies are more common in Objective-C.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html

Comment: thanks! "Flat inheritance hierarchies are more common in Objective-C" – knowing that could be a great guidance

Answer (score 0):

That means that you have poorly designed architecture for this case. Try to rethink it and use another approach. Maybe you'd better want to use aggregation instead of inheritance. For example in some implementation AGVideo has to control video playback. Maybe it is implemented as the sequence of images. Then the solution would be to aggregate multiple  AGImage instances and not inheriting from it.

If you want your class to implement functionality of different nature (e.g. both serialization and graphics rendering) the best choice would be using protocols. In this case each class would have it's own behavior for specified action but still you can manage the set of objects with different behavior but the same interface.